# Infinite loop when validating input against array

Tags: vb.net

The homework task is to simply allow the user to input a value (string) "FD__" and match it against a list of known inputs and return true/false. The ID's are already defined and it works well, when I type an ID which is defined like `Products(2)` which is "FD3" it will return true, if the value is not defined it will not only give no results but crash the program, so in conclusion true works but false does not. Any information could be helpful.

---

Design: https://i.stack.imgur.com/88xKk.png

---

```
Public Class Form1

    'variables
    Dim Products(9) As String
    Dim Entered As String
    Dim Found As Boolean

    Public Sub btnFind_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnFind.Click
        'Product variable array elements
        Products(0) = "FD1"
        Products(1) = "FD2"
        Products(2) = "FD3"
        Products(3) = "FD4"
        Products(4) = "FD5"
        Products(5) = "FD6"
        Products(6) = "FD7"
        Products(7) = "FD8"
        Products(8) = "FD9"
        Products(9) = "FD10"
        'process
        Entered = txtFind.Text 'define entered value as variable
        Found = FindNumber() 'sub function
        If Found Then
            lblResult.Text = Found 'change the results
        End If
    End Sub

    Public Function FindNumber()
        'If true statements
        Do While (Found = False)
            If Entered = Products(0) Then
                Found = True
                lblResult.ForeColor = Color.LawnGreen
            ElseIf Entered = Products(1) Then
                Found = True
                lblResult.ForeColor = Color.LawnGreen
            ElseIf Entered = Products(2) Then
                Found = True
                lblResult.ForeColor = Color.LawnGreen
            ElseIf Entered = Products(3) Then
                Found = True
                lblResult.ForeColor = Color.LawnGreen
            ElseIf Entered = Products(4) Then
                Found = True
                lblResult.ForeColor = Color.LawnGreen
            ElseIf Entered = Products(5) Then
                Found = True
                lblResult.ForeColor = Color.LawnGreen
            ElseIf Entered = Products(6) Then
                Found = True
                lblResult.ForeColor = Color.LawnGreen
            ElseIf Entered = Products(7) Then
                Found = True
                lblResult.ForeColor = Color.LawnGreen
            ElseIf Entered = Products(8) Then
                Found = True
                lblResult.ForeColor = Color.LawnGreen
            ElseIf Entered = Products(9) Then
                Found = True
                lblResult.ForeColor = Color.LawnGreen
            Else 'keeps crashing
                Found = False
                lblResult.ForeColor = Color.Red
            End If
        Loop
        Return Found
    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: It doesn't crash. `FindNumber()` is an endless loop because `Found` will be always false (Do While Found = False). Instead of a do while instruction, loop trough Products() just once and return true or false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can actually do this with **a lot** less code... I'm going to go ahead and do some critique while at it.

```
'1. Functions should have return types
'2. You should pass the function what it needs to do its job 
Public Function FindNumber(numberEntered As String) As Boolean
   'Rather than evaluating if a condition is true or false, and then returning
   'true or false, you can just directly return the condition.
   Return Products.Contains(numberEntered)
End Function
```

Then in your main program:

```
'This doesn't need to be a class level variable
Dim entered = txtFind.Text
'Local variables should be lowercase
Dim found = FindNumber(entered)
If found Then
  'With Option Strict you can't assign a Boolean to a String...
  'but you can do .ToString() instead
  lblResult.Text = found.ToString()
  'And this was really dependent on the result of the function...
  'Also it has nothing to do with finding the number...
  lblResult.ForeColor = Color.LawnGreen
Else
  lblResult.ForeColor = Color.Red
End If
```

It looks a lot longer, but take out the comments and I promise you it'll be a much simpler (and shorter) program.

Answer (score 0):

You could optimise this whole code by using the .contains function this simple used like this:

if mylist.contains("sometext") then
'change forecolor to green
else
'change forecolor to red
end if

This would mitigate your problem.

Comment: I already know that option, the problem is that the actual assignment asks you to do it like this.